# How can I store a list of return values from asynchronous goroutines?

Tags: dictionary, go, parallel-processing

I have a search function, that doesn't require the results to be ordered. It is generating a table of the stored results. I'm using a map, because it automatically removes identical values. The search function requires a lot of computing power, and I would like to execute them in parallel. My current code looks something like this:

```
func assign(a int, b int, table *map[int]byte) {
    (*table)[doSomething(a,b)] = 0
}
func incrementTable(table map[int]byte, paths []int) map[int]byte {
    newTable := make(map[int]byte)
    for p,_ := range table {
        for _,m := range paths {
            go assign(p, m, &newTable)
        }
    }
    return newTable
}
```

However, this throws an error, because it is trying to concurrently write to the same map. How can I store all of these at the same time, without a big dip in performance?

The code runs fine if I run it without the `go` keyword, so I know everything else works.

Comment: There is a sync.map which provides already the thread safety: https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 How can I use this in my case? The link doesn't provide examples of how to use it.

Comment: Thats in the STL.| https://medium.com/@deckarep/the-new-kid-in-town-gos-sync-map-de24a6bf7c2c simple googling should be sufficient

Comment: The way you implement it, the map will keep growing after function returns. Is that what you want? Your program may look at the map for a value that is not yet put in there, but will be there later. If you want a complete map, but fill it concurrently, pass a channel to the search goroutine, use a waitgroup, and collect results from the channel without a need for a sync map.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Can you show me how I would do that? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use `sync.Map`, the search function, as it is written, will be returning a map that is being concurrently filled. That means, your program may lookup an element that is not there, but will be added later.

Usually, you would want to look at the map once all the searches are done. To do that, you can use a `WaitGroup`, and a channel to read the results from the search goroutines:

```
result:=make(chan int)
wg:=sync.WaitGroup()

resultMap:=make(map[int]byte)
done:=make(chan struct{})

// Collect the results in a map
go func() {
   defer close(done)
   for r:=range result {
      resultMap[r]=0
   }
}()

for p,_ := range table {
     for _,m := range paths {
           wg.Add(1)
           go func(t table, p path) {
               defer wg.Done()
               result <- doSomething(t,p)
           }(p,m)
        }
}
wg.Wait()
close(result)
<-done // Wait for the result collector to finish
// Here, the resultMap has all the results.
```

Comment: Why do you map a string to the result? And why do you have `doSearch` in `doSearch`?  I don't really understand what the first loop is doing. (`for r:=range result`).

Comment: It is a generic example. Change that based on how your search works, and what the actual types of variables are.\

Comment: I don't really understand the example, though. For example, where would my generate function (`doSomething` in my code example) go? It would be helpful if you could put this in the frame of what I gave as my example.

Comment: See the modified code

Comment: I changed the code a bit to fit my use case. I'm getting an error: `expression in go must be function call` when I use `go func() { /* Code block here*/ }`.

Comment: Yes, see the moditied code. The collect results goroutine must be a call

Comment: Do I need to create a new function that takes in pointers and alters the variables for that part? And why is it `go doSearch`? I don't have a `doSearch` function.

Comment: Typo. Fixed again.

Comment: I got the same error as before (concurrent map write).

Comment: Where does it say concurrent write is happening?  Map is written in only one place in my code

Comment: The line that says `for r:=range result`. It has a chain of what I assume to be every single write (there's thousands of them). The beginning of the error looks like this `fatal error: concurrent map iteration and map write`.

Comment: That would be you reading from the map while result collector is still writing to it, See the updated code where I added a wait for the termination of that goroutine.

Comment: It isn't generating the paths anymore. It only has 1 or occasionally 2 paths instead of the ~600k it should have.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in `doSometing`.

Comment: I'm writing a Rubik's cube solver. `doSomething` is a turn function. It takes an array of 20 cubies and a move and returns a new array of 20 cubies.

Comment: It returns an `int` in this code, so I can't say

Comment: It wasn't exactly what my code looks like.

Comment: There are no concurrent read/writes in this code for the `newTable`. The error should say where concurrent read/write happening (both of them)

Comment: I fixed it, based on your updated code. There's no error anymore, it just generates 1-2 scrambles instead of 600,000.

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. Thank you for your help, though!